# Common application toolbar or header

Tags: oracle-adf

In my application in ADF there is a requirement that it should  have a common header or toolbar for whole application (having eight to ten .jspx files) where some buttons are enable/disabled based on the functionality of the specific page.

- we have to implement toolbar for each and every page?
  (ie, have buttons in each and every page  and have actions individually).
- if yes then what is the best solution?
- if not there is any mechanism to achieve this?

I did not found a solution for the above scenario on the net, why, I don't know or I am confusing with simple thing, which as a "novice" I am not getting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look into page templates in ADF - for example:
http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/developer-tools/adf/learnmore/24-generic-toolbar-component-169163.pdf

Comment: :Thanks for your answer. you definitely provide some insight on this, and i will look into this,But i am having a question like cant i use pagetemplates or pagefragments to acheive the same?

Comment: Yes you can use a page template and have the toolbar there, and then in each page pass to the template the names of the methods that the toolbar should call.